Why is initialValue not optional in reduce.call?
Why is initialValue not optional in reduce.call?
For example,
// Error when calling reduce.call without initialValue.
// Error: Expected 3 arguments, but got 2.
Array.prototype.reduce.call(
  document.querySelectorAll<HTMLButtonElement | HTMLInputElement>('button, input[type="button"]'),
  (accumulator: HTMLButtonElement | HTMLInputElement, currentValue: HTMLButtonElement | HTMLInputElement) => (
    accumulator.value < currentValue.value ? currentValue : accumulator
  )
)

// No error If convert to array.
Array.prototype.slice.call(
  document.querySelectorAll<HTMLButtonElement | HTMLInputElement>('button, input[type="button"]')
).reduce(
  (accumulator: HTMLButtonElement | HTMLInputElement, currentValue: HTMLButtonElement | HTMLInputElement) => (
    accumulator.value < currentValue.value ? currentValue : accumulator
  )
)

// No error If convert to array.
[
  ...document.querySelectorAll<HTMLButtonElement | HTMLInputElement>('button, input[type="button"]')
].reduce(
  (accumulator: HTMLButtonElement | HTMLInputElement, currentValue: HTMLButtonElement | HTMLInputElement) => (
    accumulator.value < currentValue.value ? currentValue : accumulator
  )
)

But, why is initialValue not optional in reduce.call?
